# Black lines in the minimap area in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-artifacts

Has anyone come across this problem? Is this a graphics artifact or a feature?  Sorry if this is a stupid question. So far I haven't been able to reproduce it yet. Thanks in advance.

[Here is an example of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C2km.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN What more information do you require? The mini-map on the right side fills with black lines and the syntax highlighter goes wonky.. like [so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRGyz.png). It very irritating and it would be nice if someone knew of a fix or a workaround.

Comment: This still happens on VS Code 1.85.1. Should probably create an issue about this.

Comment: Actually, I just found a workaround! Disable the `editor.minimap.renderCharacters` and it goes away. I don't think there's really any benefit in rendering the characters since the minimap is so small that I wouldn't be able to make out the characters anyway. It looks just fine with the color block rendering. :)